# How to dynamically set 'name' attribute of a simple form input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, parameters, strong-parameters

I am using Simple Form in a Rails application in which a FormsController controller was defined as follow :

```
class FormsController < ApplicationController
  def index
      @forms = Form.all
  end

  def new
    @form = Form.new(form_params)
  end

  ...

  private
    def form_params
      params.require(:form).permit(:user, :name, :tag, :link, :repo)
    end
end
```

A `new` view is used to get some inputs from user

```
<div class="form">
  <%= simple_form_for @param do |f| %>
    <div class="form-inputs";>
      <%= f.input :user %>
      <%= f.input :name %>
      <%= f.input :tag %>
      <%= f.input :link %>
      <%= f.input :repo %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit, "Create", class: "btn-primary" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I checked what's the generated name for a each field using inspect :

```
<input type="text" name="form[user]" id="form_user">
```

Printing parameters in controller while submitting a form returns :

```
{“user”=>”value1”, “name”=>”value2”, “tag”=>”value3”, “link”=>”value4”, “repo”=>”value5”}
```

From now, I would like to duplicate that's simple form few times. So, I first updated the field name from `form[<parameter>]` to `form[1][<parameter>]`

```
   <div class="form-inputs";>
      <%= f.input :user, input_html: { name: 'form[1][user]' } %>
      <%= f.input :name, input_html: { name: 'form[1][name]' } %>
      <%= f.input :tag, input_html: { name: 'form[1][tag]' } %>
      <%= f.input :link, input_html: { name: 'form[1][link]' } %>
      <%= f.input :repo, input_html: { name: 'form[1][repo]' } %>
    </div>
```

What I get from now as parameters output is :

```
"form"=>{"1"=>{"“user”"=>"value1", "“name”"=>"value2", "“tag”"=>"value3", "“link”"=>"value4", "“repo”"=>"value5"}}
```

**What's the best way to dynamically allocate the id to the `form[<id>][user]` to the field ?**

**Is it possible to get parameters formatted as follow ?**

```
form => { 1 => {user: "user1" }, 2 => {user: "user2" }, 3 => {user: "user3" }.. }
form => { 1 => {name: "name1" }, 2 => {name: "name2" }, 3 => {name: "name3" }.. }
...
```

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38191501/simple-form-multiple-forms-for-same-resource-type-on-page

Comment: Which `id` are you referring to? The object you're creating or an object in a different model?